# How to get Visual Studio Team Service TFS_analysis connection details

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

does any one know how to get the connection details of visual studio team service tfs_analysis database, so I could create an excel pivot table that connect to this database/cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no data warehouse in VSTS. For reporting, look into the built-in dashboard capabilities or Power BI, which has a VSTS data connector.

Comment: does the Power BI with VSTS data connector charges you when you use it? I saw it but I didn't try as I may incur fees/charges @Daniel

Comment: @FerdzM You can easily search the web for pricing information. There is a free tier.